# Adding a dictionary to Eclipse for spell checking other than the english one

Tags: java, eclipse, spell-checking, eclipse-kepler

How to add (or create) a foreign dictionary for spell checking in Eclipse Kepler ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this through the spelling option in

Window >> Preferences >> spelling

and select user defined dictionary, you can create a custom .txt file, with a word on each line

that should do the trick..

Comment: No problem.. If you cant see spelling type it into the box and it will appear....

Comment: But is it possible to use two dictionaries in the same time..forcing eclipse to check in them in same time ?

Comment: There is the platform dictionary, this is preinstalled, either UK or US english, the "User Defined" section allows for extra word to be added to this list, so your choices are English and others or just plain old english... what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: English and others in the same time. so in my source code if I write in many languages, Eclipse wont warn me for spelling problems :)

Comment: Ok then you can go and create a word list for your other languages, its easily done in ruby or PHP to create lists, its not the most optimal solution. or you could go and install the required language pack from here, http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/L-3.2_Language_Packs-200607121700/